# How to perform content negotiation in django middleware?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.6, django-middleware, django-2.2

Let say i have a Custom `Django Middleware` which check request header has jwt token if not return rest_framework `Response`.,

```
middleware.py

@staticmethod
def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    try:
        jwt_token = request.headers["token"]
    except KeyError:
        response = Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        return response
```

but i am getting error like

> .accepted_renderer not set on Response

how to perform content-negotiation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were using [DRF's **`Response`** class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/).
You should use [**Django's `HttpResponse` class**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) as,

```
# middleware.py
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


@staticmethod
def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    try:
        jwt_token = request.headers["token"]
    except KeyError:
        response = HttpResponse(status=403)
        return response
```

---

---

### UPDATE-1

I'm not sure whetehr this method is ***good*** or ***bad***, but it's works well.

Create a dummy view, that return **`DRF Response`** and use it to return the response.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


@api_view()
def custom_view(request):
    return Response(status=403)


class Foo(...):

    @staticmethod
    def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        try:
            jwt_token = request.headers["token"]
        except KeyError:
            return custom_view(request)
```

Comment: Ya i using JsonResponse instead but the problem is we can't take advantage of browsable API

Comment: You can't take advantage of DRF Browsable API from ***middleware***.

Comment: DRF Response is subclass of `SimpleTemplateResponse` which is Subclass of `HttpResponse` right.

Comment: Yeah. But, If a custom subclass of HttpResponse implements a render method, Django will treat it as emulating a SimpleTemplateResponse, and the render method must itself return a valid response object. [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse)

Comment: and the [**`.accepted_renderer`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#accepted_renderer) attribute set automatically by the APIView or @api_view immediately before the response is returned from the view.

Comment: Can I ask you one thing, Why do you need Browsable API? Here, you are only returning a ***status code*** without any content.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan I found one workaround. Check my **`U[date-1`** section

Comment: very nice solution.

Comment: one quick fix., we need to add `http_method_names`  like `@api_view(http_method_names=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "DELETE"])` to prevent `405` errors.